# Flutter extract Text widget and modify it at different places

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `data` which is being used in different `Text`. Below is the code snippet.

```
var data = "Hello world";

Text(
  data,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
);

Text(
  data,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
);

Text(
  data,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
);
```

As you can see `Text(data)` is common among all, so I thought I could make something like:

```
var text = Text("Hello World");

text.copyWith(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10));

text.copyWith(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15));

text.copyWith(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20));
```

But this isn't possible, anyone can tell me how to can I achieve something like this?

Comment: so you wanna replace Text(data,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)); with text.copyWith(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)); . Dont see the benefit, even if it would work. You code the same amount of code after all.

Comment: @Marc I think in first case, I am creating 3 different `Text` and in 2nd I am just reusing one instance of `Text`

Comment: That wouldnt be the case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can doing it by making it a function ?

Something like this maybe :

```
Widget textFunction(int fontsize){
    return Text(
             data,
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontsize),
           );
}
```

And you call it like this :

```
...
textFunction(10),
textFunction(15),
textFunction(20),
...
```

Comment: Thank you I know I can do that this way but I am not looking for a function for it.

Comment: if you want to make your second snippet of code works, do this : var text1 = Text("Hello World"); var text2 = Text("Hello World"); var text3 = Text("Hello World"); and assign the desired style to each one.

Answer (score 0):

Define fontSize variable

```
var fontSize = 5.0;
```

then use for loop

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
      Text(
        "Hello World!",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize += 5),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: i doubt that the author had that in mind. He wanted to re-use the Text Widget (in-memory possibly), because every other take on the code will produce even more complex code and most likely even more typing and thinking. To me there is no solution to this question which makes sense.

Comment: @Marc Yes, you're right, and @Lekr0 sorry this isn't I was looking, neither I  want to use my `Text` in a `Column` nor I am going to set `fontSize` multiple of `5`, for simplicity I used that code. Appreciate your response though! I thought creating a `Text` once and using it 3 or probably more time would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. I have a widget that creates a Link text (like a normal `<a></a>` html tag)

```
enum TextLinkVariations {
  EXTERNAL_LINK,
  SELF,
}

class TextLinkWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final Text label;
  final String url;
  final Widget leading;
  final Color color;
  final TextLinkVariations variation;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  TextLinkWidget(
    this.label, {
    Key key,
    this.url,
    this.onTap,
    this.variation = TextLinkVariations.SELF,
    this.leading,
    this.color,
  }) :
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          leading ??
              Icon(
                Icons.link_rounded,
                size: 14,
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.5),
              ),
          Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5)),
          Text(
            this.label.data,
            style: this.label.style.merge(
                  TextStyle(
                    color: color ??
                        this.label.style.color ??
                        defaultPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onTap: _handleOpenLink,
    );
  }
}
```

PS: Some code pieces are missing from this example but they don't contribute to solving the problem of this question...

The piece of code that solves it for me is this:

```
Text(
  this.label.data,
  style: this.label.style.merge(
    TextStyle(
      color: color ??
          this.label.style.color ??
          defaultPrimaryColor,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Because label is explicitly marked as a Text Widget, I recreate another Text widget using the Text from the constructor and then I merge/modify the styles I'm interested in modifying... In this case, just the color.

`color ?? this.label.style.color ?? defaultPrimaryColor`

It would have been splendid if the following worked for me, but it didn't :'(

```
this.label..style.merge(
                  TextStyle(
                    color: color ??
                        this.label.style.color ??
                        defaultPrimaryColor,
                  ),
                )
```